# I'm attempting to make an animation with Timer and TimerTask and paintComponent; why doesn't the image appear when the Timer Integer == 2

Tags: java

The following code is the start of an animation of a dog going through a running cycle.

When the secondsPassed integer variable equals two I want the boolean variable called first (which stands for the first image) to change to true, and then call repaint() to make the class draw the first image. But for some reason it doesn't work.

I can't figure out why it won't draw the image...

Package:

```
package Animation;
```

Imports:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
```

Description:

```
/**
 * Created by Andrea on 7/23/2017.
 */
```

Class and inheritance:

```
public class RunningDog extends JPanel {
```

Fields:

```
    private static JPanel p;
    private TimerTask task;
    private Timer timer;
    private int delay = 1000;
    private int period = 1000;
    private int secondsPassed = 0;
    private boolean first = false;
    private boolean second = false;

    private BufferedImage imageFirst;
    private BufferedImage imageSecond;
```

Start the timer:

```
    public void go(){
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
    }
```

Constructor that sets up the background and images and facilitates the timer:

```
    public RunningDog(){
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        try{
            imageFirst = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Andrea\\Desktop\\First.png"));
            imageSecond = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Andrea\\Desktop\\First.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        timer = new Timer();
        task = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                secondsPassed++;
                System.out.println(secondsPassed);
                if(secondsPassed == 2){
                    first = true;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Paint component for drawing:

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(first){
            g.drawImage(imageFirst, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
```

Main method with an instance of the class that activates the timer and creates the JFrame:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        RunningDog r = new RunningDog();
        r.go();

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.add(new RunningDog());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: use debugger and you will see what's wrong. first check does timer go to 2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

The `RunningDog` instance that you are adding to the `JFrame` has not called `go()`. Instead add the object that you made: `r`.

```
RunningDog r = new RunningDog();
r.go();

JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setSize(300, 300);
f.add(r); // change this line
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @arthur :D